# RPL_Plugin in old visual studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to rebuild an old c++ project in visual studio but I am confused on what this "RPL_Plugin.h"  file is referring to. I have tried doing some research online but nothing really pops up on what this plugin actually is. Does anyone know what this is or where to get it? I need it to build an old project in visual studio 2019 that also contained old intel compiler projects  but can't seem to find anything about RPL_Plugin or what RPL(Refactoring Pattern Language maybe? but no download or anything for it) stands for. If anyone could help guide me to where I can download this and where to look up info on this I would really appreciate it.

Also, there are a few intel compiler based functions that seems to be deprecated such as ippiResize_32f_C1R but doesn't seem like the legacy files i found for the older intel compilers does not contain them. Is there another version of these functions?

Comment: Welcome to to the fantastic world of proprietary software :-P    More seriously, I suppose you checked that this is not part of the project itself. Maybe you can just recreate a project from scratch and add all the sources. If the project is big, a script can help.

Comment: Unfortunately i did check all parts of the project itself and it was nowhere to be seen. There are only a very few files that actually use the plugin, but I can probably check if the project itself does use those files as I have seen parts that are not used anymore, so maybe I can recreate without those files (hopefully).

Comment: I still don't find any information about RPL_Plugin. I suggest that you could submit it to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: I will try submitting it to there and see if they can find anything, it is weird how there is practically no information on this though.